# Substring() usage confusion

Tags: c#, string

What does this code do?

```
txtCardNo.Text.Trim().Substring((txtCardNo.Text.Trim().Length - 4), 4)
```

Comment: At least it's not something like `txtCardNo.Text.Trim().Reverse().Take(4).Reverse();`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It gets last 4 characters from `txtCardNo` (without leading or ending spaces) but it would be better if it was like this:

```
var result = txtCardNo.Text.Trim();
result = result.Substring(result.Length - 4);
```

---

EDIT:

Also, note that this will throw error if trimmed string has less than 4 characters. You could handle it with something like this:

```
var result = txtCardNo.Text.Trim();
if (result.Length >=4)
   result = result.Substring(result.Length - 4);
else
   // do domething
```

Answer (score 3):

It's getting the last four digits of the card number.

To break it down:

```
txtCardNo.Text = the contents of the Card Number textbox
.Trim() = removes spaces from the end
.Substring(x,y) = returns y characters from the string, starting at position x
```

In this case, position x is the length of the string minus 4, so we're returning the last four characters.